# Connection error while using cqlsh

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, cqlsh

I already installed Cassandra using synaptic in Ubuntu 15.10.Cassandra service is active .But when I type cqlsh in terminal.It is showing error like below.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.4.0' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.2.1']",)})
```

What should I do to make cqlsh work on my machine?

Comment: The `cqlsh` you are using is of the same version as the installed Cassandra? Try using the `--cqlversion` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try cqlsh, by specifying  the **cqlversion** parameter with the version **'3.2.1**' as  shown in the error along with IP address of host.

Answer (score 0):

Version mismatch:
* the version which you have installed for cqlsh is 3.4.0, released on 2016-03-08
* the supported version of cqlsh is 3.2.1, released on 2016-01-19
Did you perform Cassandra upgrade (had it previously installed) or install?